# What does the "< " symbol mean on -jar call?

Tags: java, command, sh, popen

I'm facing a problem with calling java from php on a linux server with popen.

```
$java = '/usr/bin/java';
$cmd = "$java -jar javafiles/register.jar < $tmpFile";
```

What does the < before $tmpFile mean? Because apparently it is loading the content of $tmpFile from disk and inputting it directly on the console of the register.jar execution. Is that the case? Because the content of $tmpFile has special characters and these aren't being encoded in the right charset.

Comment: Yes.  The `<` operator reads the file and feeds it to the the process's  "stdin"  pipe

Comment: This would be the same with any other linux command, correct? It's not a java specific feature.

Comment: @Patrickdev: right, it has nothing to do with java, it works that way with any process that reads from stdin.

Answer (score 3):

Thats exactly what it does.  Specifically, it runs the program and sends the contents of `$tmpFile` into the standard input (System.in) of the program being executed.